# Unregistering an app-wide ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I'd like to be notified about the changes to the contacts provider, so I decided to implement a custom `ContentObserver`:

```
public class ContactsChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private final WeakReference<Context> contextRef;

    public ContactsChangeObserver(Context context) {
        super(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
        this.contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        Context context = contextRef.get();
        if (context != null) {
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

I'm mostly interested in receiving the updates while my application is in background, so the code in `onChange` will probably just set a flag into `SharedPreferences` for later processing. I'm registering the observer in a custom `Application` class' `onCreate` method. The problem with this approach is obviously that there's no straightforward way to unregister the observer, which will lead to a number of stale observers if my application is recreated multiple times. So my question is whether there's a better way to implement my use case?

Comment: If your "application is recreated", that means the old process was terminated, in which case all the memory and objects from the old process are gone. How you will wind up with "stale observers"?

Comment: My guess is that registerObserver() will pass the object to a system service, so if I don't unregister it explicitly, the system service will never know that it has become invalid. That means it's possible to register a lot of content observers by restarting the application process. @CommonsWare, can you please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: "so if I don't unregister it explicitly, the system service will never know that it has become invalid" -- that has to be handled by the OS. Processes are terminated without warning all the time; Android cannot be relying on developers unregistering everything.

Comment: Makes sense, just trying to be a "good citizen".